# Como posso usar algo parecido com um IF em uma query SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, if, condição

Estou aplicando uma query `SQL` no **Oracle SQL Developer** em multiplas tabelas onde uma `Column` de uma view fica nula em alguns lugares e então eu precisarei usar valores de outra `Column` e  não sei usar muito bem o IF da query. 
Alguem pode ajudar com algumas possíveis soluções?

E.g.

```sql
SELECT x.Column1 "Alias",
       y.Column2 "Alias2",
FROM table x
INNER JOIN table y
ON (IF x.Column3 or x.Column4) = y.Column2 
.
.
.
```

Comment: Você está usando o Oracle ou MySQL? Descreveu um e pôs a tag de outro.

Comment: Opa obrigado pelo aviso, eu me passei desculpe-me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução no Oracle

```
SELECT x.Column1 "Alias",
       y.Column2 "Alias2",
FROM table x,table y
ON NVL(x.Column3,x.Column4) = y.Column2
```

Mas **em geral** problemas deste tipo aconselham à uma revisão do Modelo.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, revisar o modelo eh um trabalho que nao posso ter agora rsrsr mas vou considerar com total certeza! tenha um bom dia

Answer (score 1):

No MySQL pode ser utilizado da seguinte forma, como praticamente já estava fazendo:

```
SELECT x.Column1 "Alias",
       y.Column2 "Alias2",
FROM table x
INNER JOIN table y
ON (x.Column3 = y.Column2 OR x.Column4 = y.Column2)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela solução vou testá-la e averiguar qual a que melhor soluciona, muito obrigado!